# HELP: UDP broadcast vlc stream weirdness!

Tags: command-line, udp, broadcast, vlc, multicast

Hi I'm trying using vlc to broadcast UDP stream within a LAN, Making it like a TV channel.

I used command line to launch VLC which then vlc is ok to run =

```
cvlc --repeat filename.avi --sout '#standard{access=udp,mux=ts,dst=239.255.12.42:8001}
```

problem is it works on some network, and I have problem receiving it on a network without router!

Question: what is some magical about the address "239.255.x.x" ? what network hardware is require for UDP broadcast besides switches and cables? Does wireless can accept UDP broadcast?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: cvlc is another command, console vlc,which launch no GUI via X11, I think its equivalent to `vlc -I dummy`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 239.255.x.x addresses are part of the multicast address space, ranging from 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255 (and there are some specific-use areas in there).

You've correctly noted that it doesn't work without a router. This is because the basic IP stack still wants to know how to route those addresses to determine which interface to send them on. You can either add a static route for multicast (that address or all multicast addresses), or put in a default gateway.

Answer (score 2):

[Read about using command line options here.](http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch04.html)

More specific answer:

```
standard (alias std)

Sends a stream.

Options:

access: how to send: file, udp, rtp, http.

mux: which muxer (ie, which format) will be used. It can be one of avi (for AVI format) ogg (for OGG format) ps (for MPEG2-PS format) ts (for MPEG2-TS format).

url: if you use the file access, it will be the location where to store the stream; if you use another access, it will be the unicast or multicast IP address where you want to stream.

sap: if you use the udp or rtp accesses, use this option to announce your stream, using SAP/SDP.

name! This option contains the name under which you want to announce the program.

slp: like sap, but use the SLP protocol. You need to have libslp on your system.

sap_ipv: if you use the sap option, use this option to specify if you want to send the SAP announces in IPv4 or IPv6. The value of this option is 4 or 6.
```

Comment: Hi Charles Ray, thanks for you answer. I do have read the manual multiple times. But the multicast just doesn't work on some network environment.

Comment: Are you making sure the ports are open on receiving end of the connection? There could be many different possibilities.

Comment: Yer, open, same machines (server, client), in a new network, the become unusable. only diff = missing a route, ip address is manually set. is it require to have a router or a gateway to have UDP broadcast to be working?

Comment: Yup, a router is needed, see my answer.